# Dynamic expression in Python

Tags: python, pandas, data-science

I will get condition from json file where the condition is '<=' and need to compare two columns containing dates.

So I tried as below:

```
                left = y['predicate']['left']
                right = y['predicate']['right']
                grp1 = y['groupby']['groupByFields']
                grp2 = y['groupby']['aggregateField']
                ope = y['groupby']['aggregateOperation']
                res = y['groupby']['result']
                logic = y['predicate']['logic']
                result[left] = pd.to_datetime(result[left])
                result[right] = pd.to_datetime(result[right])
                res = result.loc[result[left] + eval(logic) + result[right]]
```

By using the following code it is working perfectly

```
res = result.loc[result[left] <= result[right]]
```

and i tried these also

```
res = result.loc[eval(str(result[left]) +" " + logic +" " + str(result[right]))]
```

I am getting error.

Comment: Please edit this question so that it contains the error you are getting.

Answer (score 2):

[Please do not use `eval`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1832940/why-is-using-eval-a-bad-practice). It is very dangerous - almost always more dangerous than you expect - and there is rarely a good reason to use it. The current problem is definitely not a good reason.

Instead, simply use the `logic` string to look up a function which can do the comparison. The standard library module `operator` provides such functions:

```py
import operator

ops = {
    '==': operator.eq, '!=': operator.ne,
    '<=': operator.le, '>=': operator.ge,
    '<': operator.lt, '>': operator.gt
}

# later:
res = result.loc[ops[logic](result[left], result[right])]

# Error handling is left as an exercise.
```

You can also create such named functions yourself:

```py
def eq(x, y):
    return x == y
```

Or use `lambda`: `ops = {'eq': (lambda x, y: x == y), ...`

In all cases, the lookup should contain [*the functions themselves, not the result of a call*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33195344/python-run-functions-from-lookup-table).

Answer (score 1):

This is because `str(result[left])` and `str(result[right])` cause these dataframe columns to be printed, while you want them to become `result[left] {logic} result[right]`.

```py
logic = ">=" # For example
res = result.loc[eval(f"result[left] {logic} result[right]")]
```

using f-string formatting (Python 3.6+)

Note: [Use `eval` are your own risk.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35804961/python-eval-is-it-still-dangerous-if-i-disable-builtins-and-attribute-access) I would advise using other methods. There's other comments that outline some.

Comment: Thanks @Tom Aarsen Its working.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`DataFrame.query`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.query.html) with `f-strings`:

```
res = result.query(f"{left} {logic} {right}")
```

Comment: Is this eval-based under the hood? Or does Pandas have its own expression parser?

Comment: @KarlKnechtel - `does Pandas have its own expression parser` ? Yes, if use string `<=` or `>=` or `==` it working well.